# SQL, Show all entries where count from different tables is unqeual

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following two SELECTs:

```
Declare @S_PWO varchar(300)
Declare @S_O varchar(300)
@S_PWO = 
(
SELECT COUNT(PWO.Attr1)
FROM Person P
JOIN PersonInOrg PIO
  ON P.UID_Person = PIO.UID_Person
JOIN Org O
  ON O.UID_Org = PIO.UID_Org
JOIN PersonWantsOrg PWO
  ON PIO.Attr2 = PWO.Attr3
WHERE 
  O.Attr4 like '%STRING%' AND
  P.UID_Person = 'XXXXXXXXX'
)
@S_O =
(
SELECT Count(O.CCC_DisplayName)
FROM Person P
JOIN PersonInOrg PIO
  ON P.UID_Person = PIO.UID_Person
JOIN Org O
  ON O.UID_Org = PIO.UID_Org
JOIN PersonWantsOrg PWO
  ON PIO.Attr2 = PWO.Attr3
WHERE 
  O.Attr4 like '%STRING%' AND
  P.UID_Person = 'XXXXXXXXX'
)
```

For the person XXXXXXXXX they may result in an equal count, or in an unequal count.
I now need to find all persons where the count of those two Selects is unqueal.
How do i do that?

Comment: Sorry, i added it

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using the same Join/Where in both Selects, only the Count differs.

Simply combine both into one, Group By `UID_Person` and apply `Having`:

```
SELECT P.UID_Person, Count(PWO.Attr1) AS cntAttr1, Count(O.CCC_DisplayName) AS cntDisplayName
FROM Person P
JOIN PersonInOrg PIO
JOIN PersonInOrg PIO
  ON P.UID_Person = PIO.UID_Person
JOIN Org O
  ON O.UID_Org = PIO.UID_Org
JOIN PersonWantsOrg PWO
  ON PIO.Attr2 = PWO.Attr3
WHERE 
  O.Attr4 LIKE '%STRING%'
GROUP BY P.UID_Person
HAVING Count(PWO.Attr1) <> Count(O.CCC_DisplayName)
```